# How do I share many Typescript interfaces across projects

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I've made an project that only holds typescript interfaces. So I might have files like account.ts and item.ts that only contain interfaces

```
export interface Account
{
    name: string;
}
```

How do I package up all those files locally so I can npm install (from local) and use those interfaces in other projects with something like...

```
import { Account, Item } from 'all-my-interfaces';
```

Comment: refer this: https://codeburst.io/https-chidume-nnamdi-com-npm-module-in-typescript-12b3b22f0724

Comment: You can also check npm link

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma that codeburst link help me, thank you

Comment: Sure. Can you write a small synopsis here. Would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I wrote an article on medium which addresses this.](https://medium.com/@nilayvishwakarma/build-an-npm-package-with-typescript-by-nilay-vishwakarma-f303d7072f80)

---

A quick walkthrough with only essentials:

```
> mkdir my-lib
> cd my-lib
> npm init -y
> npm i -D typescript
> touch tsconfig.json
> mkdir src
> touch src/index.ts
> touch .npmignore
```

*tsconfig.json:*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "declaration": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "strict": true
    }
}
```

*src/index.ts:*

```
export interface Check {
    isValid(): bool;
}
```

*.npmignore:*

```
dist/
```

Add the npm scripts in *package.json*:

```
"prepublishOnly": "tsc"
```

Publish:

```
npm publish
```

Now use in some other project:

```
npm i my-lib
```

Comment: Why do you add dist to .npmignore? Arent this the files supposed to be imported by other projects? Also you need to add `"main": "dist/index.js"` to package.json